# Google ads not showing on my game

Tags: android, admob, unity-game-engine, ads

Well i have my google banner ad script and google mobile ads plugin but for some reason ads are not shown in app after i publish it

When using test ID they work when im testing them

```
using GoogleMobileAds.Api;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class AdScript : MonoBehaviour {

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {

    showBannerAd();

}

private void showBannerAd()
{
    string adID = "ca-app-pub-4076551740851810/4176317920";

    //ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111 FOR TESTING
    //***For Testing in the Device***
    //AdRequest request = new AdRequest.Builder()
             // Simulator.
        //.AddTestDevice("1e84e34350774f47")  // My test device.
        //.Build();

    //***For Production When Submit App***
    AdRequest request = new AdRequest.Builder().Build();

    BannerView bannerAd = new BannerView(adID, AdSize.SmartBanner, AdPosition.Bottom);
    bannerAd.LoadAd(request);
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {

}
}
```

I have registered them on admob and linked it to my google acc i belive i will provide screen shots and eny additional information if needed

Comment: please capture logs and upload in your question, you should see error code for admob

Answer (score 0):

Does your layout have the correct setup by including the below code?

```
<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
            xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:id="@+id/adView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            ads:adSize="BANNER"
            ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-4076551740851810/4176317920">
        </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>
```

Comment: I checked every xml file i didnt find such thing tho if i didnt have that how is the rest of my code not giving me an error ?

Comment: For some reason on my interstitial ad i have IsLoaded set up without eny errors   if (interstitial.IsLoaded())
  {
   interstitial.Show(); but still they also dont work

Comment: what do u mean ? ++ my add is showing when im using the test id